# Can I use AR Parrot Drone 2.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 instead of Mac and Windows?

Tags: windows, mac, npm

I am highly interested to make a project from here

https://www.instructables.com/id/Autonomous-AR-Parrot-Drone-20-Flying/

I have extracted the sentences from the project website below:

> This instructable will give you an EXTREMELY simple and quick way (<
>   15 minutes) to have an AR Parrot Drone 2.0 fly autonomously with code
>   written by you! The best part of this project is it only requires the
>   drone and a laptop **(mac or windows)**. No modifications to the
>   drone.

Now, before proceeding for the implementation I just want to be sure that will there be any compatibility problem since I am using **Ubuntu 16.04** **LTS**? 
Because the project mentioned about **Mac and Windows only**.

Any clarifications would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project uses Node.JS, and Node.JS is available for Linux, so I would tend to say yes.